# Difference between cart table and order table in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on an online store website.
I need to make a shopping cart.

I am confused, in order to make the shopping cart, I must make a cart table in my database (having the customer_id,product_id,qty,price) ..
And then when the customer checks out the cart, I must make another table (order) that stores the order checked out ??
Then I must make 2 tables, one for storing the cart and one for storing the order when checked out?

Storing the checked out order in a database is logical (Since it doesn't need much updates..)

BUT.. Is storing the cart in a database efficient? Imagine whenever a customer adds an item to the cart, I must use an INSERT query, and then when a customer increment the qty or decrement, I must use an UPDATE query, and then when a customer removes a cart DELETE query... 
Knowing that usually customers add to cart many times and then remove without checking out.. maybe changed their minds?

What is the logical solution??

Thanks for the help

Comment: Isn't a cart simply an order that hasnt been 'checked out'? If I go shopping online, fill up my cart and then go through checkout, then, on my next visit, I would expect my cart to be empty, so I think a cart and an order are the same thing (so, same table) - but I don't know if that's how the standard shopping cart apps do it!

Comment: That is exactly what I want to know! Are cart and order the same? Or we must make 2 tables?
What you mean is we make checkedout as a column in the table ? @Strawberry

Comment: The thing is; the order will equal to cart when it is completed - order is not frequently updated. Those two are different concepts - may be equal to each other in some time. Most of the time order will be null, while cart is updated.

Comment: can you clarify more? @Ersoy didn't get your answer

Comment: Cart and order are different concepts. Order is null at the beginning, order will exists when the payment is made. Until the payment there is no order. When payment is completed then there is no cart. "Cart" will be frequently accessed, inserted, updated while "Order" will be less accessed, once inserted, "maybe" updated (return etc). It is better to keep them as separate concepts. They may be equal the each other just after the payment - before truncating the cart .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your business. If your business requires;

- You may save in their cookie, local storage if user is not logged in to your web site.
- You may get all the cart from cookie and save into your database if user is authenticated
- If there is no-login payment then you don't have to move them between user's cookie and database.
- If the user may log-in from multiple platforms and you want to unify the cart then you need to save the cart in your database(mysql or any other one).

You may use another database technologies such as `redis` hashes with expire option. It is pretty fast and i think it covers all the requirements of `cart`.

- create a hash with the session identifier
- use `EXPIRE` to set time-to-live (24 hours maybe) - O(1)
- use `HSET` to add products with their amount - O(1) for each field/value
- use `HINCRBY` to increase the amount - O(1)
- use `HDEL` to remove products with their respective amount - O(1) for single field
- use `HGETALL` to get all the cart. - O(N) for number of fields.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:somesessionidentifier:cart productid:2 5
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> expire user:somesessionidentifier:cart 86400
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ttl user:somesessionidentifier:cart
(integer) 86394
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:somesessionidentifier:cart productid:3 1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:somesessionidentifier:cart productid:92 1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hset user:somesessionidentifier:cart productid:5 1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall user:somesessionidentifier:cart
1) "productid:2"
2) "5"
3) "productid:3"
4) "1"
5) "productid:92"
6) "1"
7) "productid:5"
8) "1"
127.0.0.1:6379> HINCRBY user:somesessionidentifier:cart productid:2 1
(integer) 6
127.0.0.1:6379> HDEL user:somesessionidentifier:cart productid:5
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall user:somesessionidentifier:cart
1) "productid:2"
2) "6"
3) "productid:3"
4) "1"
5) "productid:92"
6) "1"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: then you mean I must make 2 separate tables (cart and order) ?

Comment: Yes. You may keep orders in your mysql. Cart will be a temporary one - order will persist infinitely. Since cart will be frequently accessed and updated, i offered `redis`.  @T.AS

Comment: Alright. Actually it's the first time I hear about redis. I don't know If I will be able to use it now.

I have another suggestion, Can I just make cart and order in the same table. and I make "ischeckedout" a column in the table, if the order is checked out then "ischeckedout" = 1 , else =0.. 

And when I need to get data about orders made and sales made, then I retrieve the data from table with a condition where "ischeckedout"==1 ..

Is this a good solution? What is it's negatives?

@Ersoy

Comment: If there are huge inserts/updates/deletes into that table due to cart related actions, it will affect the "orders" too. I don't want my customers to see their orders "very slow" whenever some people have a super active cart, since they share the same table. I am not an e-commerce expert but i would separate them due to one is "temporary and has lifetime"  while the other is "infinite". It can be done, but for scalability i wouldn't recommend to use the same table with boolean flags. As i stated at the beginning; "It depends on your business" and the scale of it. @T.AS

Comment: Ok alright.

Another suggestion .. 
Could it be that shopping cart is just an instantaneous process that a customer makes in order to make order, if checked out (data is inserted to the order table) then if he didn't checkout, nothing happens.

I mean I can make a cart page with a table having form with (price retrieved from product table in database, and qty input that will be submitted) ..
Once the person add to the cart, this page will have the data of the added product, with the ability to order. If customer didn't order, and went to another page, shopping cart will be empty.

Comment: yes but cart will be valid for some time period even the user goes to cart page and leaves - it will have some lifetime. You will need to periodically delete old cart data - cron maybe.  @T.AS

Comment: Then I must use sessions ? @Ersoy

Comment: it depends on your business rules and decisions, if you are going to unify the cart across all the logged in users - when user log-in from web and add some products to cart, then he log-in from phone you may want to show the cart of web in the mobile - you may use session, you may use separate table with cron - you may use redis to control lifetime or share carts across the devices etc etc. I proposed one solution as answer which covers all the topics i listed in the answer. @T.AS

Comment: @T.AS if the question is solved in your side, could you please approve to finalize it ?

Comment: how can i finalize it ? @Ersoy

Comment: You may tell me :) i provided multiple/alternative answers for the questions. If you don't have any further related to this topic then i think it is finalized. @T.AS